# <input type='file' ... en Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, html5, archivo

Tengo una serie de  a los cuales desde el navegador Microsoft Edge no puedo acceder a sus caracteristicas ya que la consulta mediante Jquery devuelve undefined, en cambio desde otros como Chrome, Firefox u Opera si. Estos los almaceno en un array llamado ListadoFicheros

A continuación muestro el código HTML5 con el que estoy trabajando.

```html
<div class="containerFixed col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 addMarginTop" id="panelDocumentos">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="container-fluid panel-container">
          <div class="text-left col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            DOCUMENTOS
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 required" aria-required="true">Selecciona documento</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 paddingLeft0">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-8 col-lg-8 paddingLeft0">
              <input class="form-control col-md-3" id="fileName" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 paddingLeft0">
              <div class="file_input_div paddingLeft0 paddingRigth0" style="display:inline;">
                <a id="button" class="btnSubirFichero btn btn-danger col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-12"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Seleccionar </a>
                <input type="file" id="documento" name="documento" class="hidden">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <label class="control-label required" for="Comentario_documento" aria-required="true">Comentario documento</label>
          <textarea class="form-control text-areas valid" cols="20" id="ComentarioDocumento" maxlength="255" name="ComentarioDocumento" rows="2" aria-describedby="ComentarioDocumento-error" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="documento" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2 pull-right addMargin10Top">
          <a class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="btnUpload"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cargar Fichero</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

        </div>
        <div id="divTablaFicheros" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="tablaFicheros" class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                    Fichero
                  </th>
                  <th class="col-xs-5 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                    Comentario
                  </th>
                  <th class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    Fecha Subida
                  </th>
                  <th class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr data-line="ListadoFicheros[0].Fichero">
                  <td class="text-center"><a style="color:#000"><i class="fa fa-file-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                  <td class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">Prueba 1</td>
                  <td class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">12/04/2018</td>
                  <td class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="paddingRigth0"><a class="btn btn-danger" id="buttonEliminarFichero"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-line="ListadoFicheros[1].Fichero">
                  <td class="text-center"><a style="color:#000"><i class="fa fa-file-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                  <td class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">Prueba 2</td>
                  <td class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">12/04/2018</td>
                  <td class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="paddingRigth0"><a class="btn btn-danger" id="buttonEliminarFichero"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div><textarea class="form-control text-areas valid hidden" cols="20" id="ComentarioDocumento" maxlength="255" name="ListadoFicheros[1].Comentario" rows="2" aria-describedby="ComentarioDocumento-error" aria-invalid="false" data-line="ListadoFicheros[1].Fichero"></textarea>
        <input
          type="file" id="documento" name="ListadoFicheros[1].Fichero" class="hidden" data-line="ListadoFicheros[1].Fichero"><textarea class="form-control text-areas valid hidden" cols="20" id="ComentarioDocumento" maxlength="255" name="ListadoFicheros[0].Comentario" rows="2" aria-describedby="ComentarioDocumento-error" aria-invalid="false" data-line="ListadoFicheros[0].Fichero"></textarea>
          <input
            type="file" id="documento" name="ListadoFicheros[0].Fichero" class="hidden" data-line="ListadoFicheros[0].Fichero">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Realizando la siguiente consulta mediante la consola

```js
$("input[name='ListadoFicheros[0].Fichero']")[0].files
```

El resultado en Edge es

```js
[object FileList]: {length: 0}
```

En cambio, si esta consulta la hago en Chrome por ejemplo, el resultado sería el siguiente

```js
FileList {0: File(3258559), length: 1}
```

¿Cual sería el motivo de esta diferencia entre los diferentes navegadores?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: A mí me devuelve datos en IE Edge: [object FileList]{0: File {...}, constructor: FileList {...}, length: 1}  https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/96344/

Comment: He cambiado el código HTML porque creo que no me había explicado muy bien. El valor que quiero obtener es el de los input hidden que siguen a <table>